# Add CAGradientLayer to view

Tags: ios, swift

I have this custom `UIView`

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupBackground()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupBackground()
    }

    private func setupBackground() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(r: 0, g: 17, b: 214).cgColor,
            UIColor(r: 0, g: 9, b: 119).cgColor
        ]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

And this is my `UIViewController`

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    let loginView = LoginView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = loginView
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `GradientLayer` doesn't show on the screen, the background is still black.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A quick glance says to me your code is good. What if instead you either (a) added `LoginView` as a child of your VC (full screen of course) or (b) tried presenting it in another VC? Sorry, I'm not at a place to try to duplicate your code. Just trying to help. Or at least pinpoint where the issue is.

Comment: I believe the frame is still CGRect.zero in your case, try adding it viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use in viewDidLoad (Load once), just declare your custom view inside like following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let loginView = LoginView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view = loginView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to init LoginView correctly at right time.

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {

  var loginView : LoginView!

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    view = LoginView.init(frame: view.bounds)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
  }

  override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
  }
}
```